# TypeError: Undefined in Javascript. Works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, undefined

Im attempting to troubleshoot some Javascript that I did not write and running into a problem. Everything works fine in Chrome but Firefox/IE are giving me nothing. The console error I get in Firefox is:

TypeError: t.h[x][i] is undefined / Line 199.

Here is the code from the beginning of the function until right past where it throws the error. The line is question is:

```
t['h'][x][i].setStyle('visibility',"visible");
```

---

```
function vcmFill() {

$('vcmresults').getElement('th').set('html',vcmData['n'] + " Results:");

var i = 0;
var k = 0;
var x = null;
var e = null;
var id = null;
var prc = "";

var ei = 0;
var ew = 0;

var t = new Array();
t['x'] = $('vcmresults').getElements('th');

t['cheese'] = $('vcmcheese').getElements('.cheese');

t['sku'] = $('vcmsku').getElements('td');
t['country'] = $('vcmcountry').getElements('td');
t['type'] = $('vcmtype').getElements('td');
t['texture'] = $('vcmtexture').getElements('td');
t['milk'] = $('vcmmilk').getElements('td');
t['brief'] = $('vcmdescription').getElements('td');
t['wine'] = $('vcmwine').getElements('td');
t['beer'] = $('vcmbeer').getElements('td');

t['cheesebtm'] = $('vcmwhy').getElements('.cheesebtm');
t['monger'] = $('vcmwhy').getElements('.cheesemonger blockquote');

t['v'] = $('vcmtbl').getElements('.vcmv');
t['h'] = $('vcmtbl').getElements('.vcmh');
for(i = 0; i < t['h'].length; i++) {
    t['h'][i] = t['h'][i].getElements('.vcmhm');
}

t['hvr'] = $$('.vcmhvrm');
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    t['hvr'][i] = { 'link': t['hvr'][i].getElement('a'), 'image': t['hvr'][i].getElement('img'), 'name': t['hvr'][i].getElement('div'), 'price': t['hvr'][i].getElement('span') };
}

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    k = vcmData['i'] + i;

    id = vcmData['a'][k]['id'];

    if(id) {

        prc = (vcmData['a'][k]['simple'] ? ((vcmData['a'][k]['on_sale'] ? "<strong>On Sale!</strong>&nbsp; " + vcmData['a'][k]['sale_price'] : vcmData['a'][k]['price']) + vcmData['a'][k]['unit']) : "Price Varies");

        t['x'][i + 1].set('html',(k + 1) + ".");
        t['cheese'][i].setStyle('visibility',"visible");
        t['cheesebtm'][i].setStyle('visibility',"visible");

        t['v'][i].setStyle('visibility',"visible");
        for(x = 0; x < t['h'].length; x++) {
            t['h'][x][i].setStyle('visibility',"visible");

        }

    } else {

        prc = "&nbsp;";

        t['x'][i + 1].set('html',"&nbsp;");
        t['cheese'][i].setStyle('visibility',"hidden");
        t['cheesebtm'][i].setStyle('visibility',"hidden");

        t['v'][i].setStyle('visibility',"hidden");
        for(x = 0; x < t['h'].length; x++) {
            t['h'][x][i].setStyle('visibility',"hidden");
        }
```

Comment: What is `$` in your code?

Comment: The JS framework is an old version of MooTools 1.2.5.1

Comment: Seems like you just need to debug your code. Clearly, there's no `[i]` member of `t['h'][x]`, so log the values to see why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Tested it by just commenting out that conditional statement and it ran correctly as it supposed to across all browsers. Just going to use that as a fix unless it comes back up in the future.